# Adding a user to configure templates

Tags: user-account

Looking to give access to a technician to help with message templates configuration eg offline receipts. What is teh best way to add a user and give access to this area only
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to give a user access to only this area. On what CMS did you install CiviCRM? You could have a look in your cms to the available permissions.